# Powershell Use string from array in a script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to make a template for various scripts to remotely do a command and then email a reciept of what happend after it's finished. Currently I'm hung up on creating a choice list of emails from an array,

```
$email = @(Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "admin*"' |
    Format-Table UserPrincipalName -A, groupemail)
```

Would be awesome if I could script out a choice between single, multiple, or the group email single option. I would like to do it this way to make room from team changes in the future. Also as a bonus if anybody knows a delfatico wait option so the command finishes and then emails the results as an attachnment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you rephrase your question? You want to make a choice selection out of the returned output from: `@(Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "admin*"' | Format-Table UserPrincipalName -A, groupemail)`?

Comment: What user properties are `UserPrincipalName -A` and `groupemail` ??

Comment: The `Format-` cmdlets emit specialized formatting directives, so they do not output a standard PowerShell object. Apply `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table` if you want store objects to a variable for further use. Try `Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "admin*"' | Format-List -Property *` to see available properties…

Comment: Yes I want to make choice from the array to send mail to specific users, cause I'm going to put that variable in the "Send to" field. And sorry it should be $groupemail from a variable I specified for the IT groups email that is not present in the user search.